# SGE: run a interacitve session (qrsh) within a batch submission (qsub)

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

I am trying to run a simple code within SGE.  However, I get very different results from same code when running from an interactive session (qrsh) or via qsub.  Mostly many codes fail to run from qsub (without any warning or error).

Is there anyway to set up an interactive session within a batch submission (running qrsh within qsub)?

> qsub test.sh

```
-V
-cwd
source MYPATH
qrsh
MYCODEHERE
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if what you ask is possible. I can think of two ways why you are observing different results.

1) Environment differences: Between cluster nodes

2) Incomplete outputs: Maybe the code runs into an edge cases (not enough memory etc.) and exits silently.

Not exactly what you asked for but just trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could submit a parallel job and then use `qrsh -inherit <hostname> <command>` to run a command under qrsh.  Unfortunately grid engine limits the number of times you can call  `qrsh -inherit` to either the number of slots in the job or one less (dependent on the job_is_first_task setting of the PE.

However it is likely that the problems are caused by a different environment between the qrsh environment and that provided by qsub by default.  If you are selecting the shell to interpret your job script in the traditional unix way (Putting `#!/bin/bash` or similar as the first line of your job script you could try adding a -l to that line to make it a login shell `#!/bin/bash -l` which is likely more similar to what you get with qrsh.